# Old code for ddply does not work

Tags: r, plyr

I have some code from the book *Longitudinal Data Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences using R* (2012) that do not work.

This is what the data looks like:

```
    subid risk gen eth ell sped  att ell2 risk2 grade read
      1  HHM   F Afr   0    N 0.94   No  DADV     5  172
      1  HHM   F Afr   0    N 0.94   No  DADV     6  185
      1  HHM   F Afr   0    N 0.94   No  DADV     7  179
      1  HHM   F Afr   0    N 0.94   No  DADV     8  194
      2  HHM   F Afr   0    N 0.91   No  DADV     5  200
      2  HHM   F Afr   0    N 0.91   No  DADV     6  210
```

The code looks like this:

```
ddply(.data = data.frame(MPLS.LS$read), .variables = .(grade = MPLS.LS$grade),
      each(read.mean = mean), na.rm = FALSE)
```

It is suppose to give me the mean of `read` over grade 5, 6, 7, and 8. But instead I get this error message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(x, ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(x, ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default(x, ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
4: In mean.default(x, ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

My question is why do I get this message? Can I change something in the code to get the result i whant?

Any help would be much appreciated becuse there is a lot of this code in the book that does not work for me.

Comment: i guess the code would be `ddply(data= MPLS.LS, .variables= .(grade), ` and sorry can't follow the `each` part.

Comment: Why do you call `data.frame()` inside your `ddply`? And don't re-specify the data later. Try `ddply(.data = MPLS.LS, .variables = .(grade),
      summarize, read.mean = mean(read, na.rm = FALSE))`. `each()` is typically used when you want to call each of several functions on one column. Since you have one function, you're better off with `summarize`.

Comment: Thanks both of you akrun and Gregor. The code you supplied works fine. I cant answer your qestions becuse I don´t know why this code was supplied in the book... Has the plyr packages been updated in some way since 2012?

Comment: Yes, plyr has been updated since then, and `ddply` in particular is pretty much deprecated and replaced by the `dplyr` package.

Comment: Aha ok that is good to know

Comment: 2012 is a long, long time ago in the R world. That would have been pre R 3.0.0 I think.

Comment: This is what Jeffery D. Long says in the book: " The ddply function of plyr is used to compute meand and SDs conditional on the time predictor. The function requires the response variable (.data=), the time predictor (.variables=.()), the statistic to be computed (.fun=), and the optional argument for handling missing data (na.rm = TRUE). Below is the syntax for computing the means for each grade remowing the missing data. The each () option is used to provide the column names for the mean in the output. When a single variable is analyzed, it must be enclosed in the data.frame () function.

Comment: betcha wish you used base r now huh

Comment: He uses R (2.12.2) does any one have recommendation for a more up to date book? I really like the scoope of this book except it is to old.

Comment: The modeling content is probably fairly current still. For data manipulation, I would recommend reading the free [dplyr vignettes](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/).

Comment: @rawr Think you forgot the "@JD Long" :)

Comment: Thanks Gregor. The main thing is that the modeling content with the lme4 package is still current and the dplyr sounds like something I have to learn how to use.

Comment: Also, I searched for errata for the book, this seems to be covered: http://studysites.sagepub.com/long/chapters/errata.txt

Comment: That is great Gregor! Thanks, this is really a great forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing my comment to an answer:

`ddply` can take your full data frame as a data argument, then you don't need to re-specify the data:

ddply(.data = MPLS.LS, .variables = .(grade), summarize,
         read.mean = mean(read, na.rm = FALSE))

`each()` is (was) typically used when you want to call *each* of several functions on one column. Since you have one function, you're better off with `summarize`.

`ddply` has been more-or-less replaced by the `dplyr` package. I would recommend learning these packages from their current documentation rather than from possibly out-of-date textbooks. `dplyr` has [quite a few vignettes](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/) that do a nice job introducing the functionality. The `dplyr` equivalent for this operation is

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(MPLS.LS, grade) %>%
  summarize(read.mean = mean(read, na.rm = FALSE))
```

`dplyr` is current and fashionable - I like it a lot - but nothing lasts forever.